# How to operate on days in Kotlin?

Tags: date, kotlin, android-calendar, days, android-date

I can get the current time like `System.currentTimeInMillis()`. But I really don't need this granularity in the millisecond range. A type which gets me a rough day date like 22.11.2021  is enough for my purposes.

I also would appreciate operations like incrementing the next 14 days etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LocalDate` as follows:

```java
fun main() {
    val currentDate = LocalDate.now()
    println(currentDate)
    val futureDate = currentDate.plusDays(14)
    println(futureDate)
}
```

You can read more about this new Time API available in Java/Kotlin at https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro.